# What are these notches in an FPC for?

Tags: cables, fpc

We are given these cute LCD displays (China made of course, drawing [here](http://www.elstore.it/wp-content/uploads/prodattach/ELSCOG12864BKWT.pdf) on page 4.)  There is a pair of notches on the connecting FPC.  They are not next to the contacts (I've seen some connector latching on these) but at 10mm from the end (a given dimension, too.)

What are these for? Some extra long FPC connector with latching or maybe some insertion tooling? Never seen them before and I wonder if these are important.

To be clear, these notches on the FPC:

[image: another display, same kind of connector]

Comment: Please post the drawing as an image inside the question and mark the parts you are asking about. The link to the datasheet can be left as a reference.

Comment: I'd speculate it's for locking by a specific type of connectors.

Comment: well, their recommended connector is quit standard

Comment: It's a unique pattern for a unique ear-tabbed connector. Good luck finding it

Answer (score 1):

It's called "notch-eared FPC".

The main purpose of the notch is to ensure a proper and more "secure" mating between the cable and the connector. It may also bring some mechanical "toughness".

Comment: the mating length is 4mm how could a notch 10mm from the end help? +1 for the structural idea however. I've also seen that in volume there are inserter robots for these connectors maybe its for that kind of manipulator

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio well, the image doesn't show much details so mine was a rough guess. When I first saw the drawing [this](https://www.molex.com/mx_upload/family/premoflex/FFC-Premo-Flex-One-Touch-15016_750x450.jpg) came to my mind as that type of cables are called notch-eared.

Comment: yep I saw these but the notch in mine are a whole 10mm from the end. Maybe they are designed for some kind of SARCOPHAGUS connector :P